# Missing dll System.Net.Security.Native in Xamarin Android app during SQL connection

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

**EDIT #2 01/18/2021**

Got it to work a while ago. Received some comments about this so I'm adding my code below for you to compare to yours/steal. From what I remember, my issue had something to do with the connection string I was using. I think the example I found had an extra parameter that was messing things up maybe?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using Xamarin.Forms;


namespace MyApp
{
    class DBConnection
    {
        private string connectionString;
        private SqlConnection connection;

        public DBConnection(string connString) 
        {
            connectionString = connString;
        }


        internal void Initialize()
        {
            CreateSQLConnection();
        }

        private void CreateSQLConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                connection = null;
                connection = new SqlConnection();
                connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
           
                if (connection != null)
                {
                    //open connection
                    connection.Open();

                    Console.WriteLine("LOG: connection established");
                    Global.gsConnectionStatus = true;

                    connection.Close();
                }
               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //ErrorHandling Here
                string exMessage = ex.Source + ex.Message + ex.ToString();
                MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "MS_Error", exMessage);
            }

        }

        public DataSet ExecuteSP(string procedureName, Dictionary<string, string> paramList)
        {
            // 1.  create a command object identifying the stored procedure
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(procedureName, connection);

            // 2. set the command object so it knows to execute a stored procedure
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // 3. add parameters to command, which will be passed to the stored procedure
            foreach (var param in paramList)
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue(param.Key, param.Value);
            }

            DataSet DSet = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                // execute the command
                //var Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                }

                SqlDataAdapter dbTable = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                dbTable.Fill(DSet);
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                //ErrorHandling Here
                string exMessage = ex.Source + ex.Message + ex.ToString();
                MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "MS_Error", exMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //ErrorHandling Here
                string exMessage = ex.Source + ex.Message + ex.ToString();
                MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "MS_Error", exMessage);
            }


            connection.Close();
            return DSet;

            
            
            
        }

    }
}
```

And here's my Connection string

```
gsConnectionString = "Data Source = tcp:111.111.111.111; Initial Catalog = AndroidDev_db; User ID = user; Password = pass";
```

**------------------Original Text Below------------------**

After searching far and wide for any reference of this dll, I come here for help.

I'm attempting to establish a connection to a SQL server db hosted my my PC (I know this isn't the best practice, but the decision isn't up to me). I've got the Android device connected via its dock/USB to my PC, and I'm running code on the device from Visual Studio 2019 in debug mode.

Code compiles and runs successfully on device until I get to my `connection.Open()` call. Once there I get several DllNotFoundExceptions and a SQLException all referencing this `System.Net.Security.Native` library that is not found.

I've gone through NuGet adding any packages that sound like they might contain what I'm looking for, but so far no luck. I've also tried adding any references that sound related, but again, nothing.

I've also tried adding `using System.Net.Security.Native;` but VS just tells me

`Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Native' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net.Security' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

And removing 'Native' doesn't fix the issue either.

Here us the log from the Output pane, just so you can see exactly what it's looking for.

```
02-04 20:15:52.362 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport attempting to load: 'System.Net.Security.Native'.
02-04 20:15:52.364 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library './System.Net.Security.Native': 'dlopen failed: library "./System.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.364 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library './libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "./libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.365 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library './libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "./libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.365 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib64/System.Net.Security.Native': '(null)'.
02-04 20:15:52.365 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib64/libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': '(null)'.
02-04 20:15:52.365 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib64/libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': '(null)'.
02-04 20:15:52.366 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'System.Net.Security.Native': 'dlopen failed: library "System.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.367 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.368 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.368 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'System.Net.Security.Native': 'dlopen failed: library "System.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.369 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library './libSystem.Net.Security.Native': 'dlopen failed: library "./libSystem.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.369 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library './libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "./libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.370 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library './libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "./libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.370 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib64/libSystem.Net.Security.Native': '(null)'.
02-04 20:15:52.370 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib64/libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': '(null)'.
02-04 20:15:52.370 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib64/libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': '(null)'.
02-04 20:15:52.371 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'libSystem.Net.Security.Native': 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.372 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.374 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.375 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'libSystem.Net.Security.Native': 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.375 W/Mono    (30702): DllImport unable to load library 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.375 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport attempting to load: 'System.Net.Security.Native'.
02-04 20:15:52.376 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library './System.Net.Security.Native': 'dlopen failed: library "./System.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.377 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library './libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "./libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.378 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library './libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "./libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.378 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib64/System.Net.Security.Native': '(null)'.
02-04 20:15:52.378 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib64/libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': '(null)'.
02-04 20:15:52.378 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib64/libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': '(null)'.
02-04 20:15:52.379 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'System.Net.Security.Native': 'dlopen failed: library "System.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.380 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.381 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.382 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'System.Net.Security.Native': 'dlopen failed: library "System.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.383 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library './libSystem.Net.Security.Native': 'dlopen failed: library "./libSystem.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.383 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library './libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "./libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.383 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library './libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "./libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.384 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib64/libSystem.Net.Security.Native': '(null)'.
02-04 20:15:52.384 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib64/libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': '(null)'.
02-04 20:15:52.384 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib64/libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': '(null)'.
02-04 20:15:52.385 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'libSystem.Net.Security.Native': 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.386 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.386 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.387 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'libSystem.Net.Security.Native': 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.387 W/Mono    (30702): DllImport unable to load library 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.393 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport attempting to load: 'System.Net.Security.Native'.
02-04 20:15:52.394 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library './System.Net.Security.Native': 'dlopen failed: library "./System.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.394 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library './libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "./libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.395 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library './libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "./libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.395 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib64/System.Net.Security.Native': '(null)'.
02-04 20:15:52.395 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib64/libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': '(null)'.
02-04 20:15:52.395 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib64/libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': '(null)'.
02-04 20:15:52.396 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'System.Net.Security.Native': 'dlopen failed: library "System.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.396 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.397 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.398 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'System.Net.Security.Native': 'dlopen failed: library "System.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.398 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library './libSystem.Net.Security.Native': 'dlopen failed: library "./libSystem.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.399 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library './libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "./libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.399 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library './libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "./libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.400 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib64/libSystem.Net.Security.Native': '(null)'.
02-04 20:15:52.400 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib64/libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': '(null)'.
02-04 20:15:52.400 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib64/libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': '(null)'.
02-04 20:15:52.401 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'libSystem.Net.Security.Native': 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.401 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.402 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.403 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'libSystem.Net.Security.Native': 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.403 W/Mono    (30702): DllImport unable to load library 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.403 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport attempting to load: 'System.Net.Security.Native'.
02-04 20:15:52.404 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library './System.Net.Security.Native': 'dlopen failed: library "./System.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.404 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library './libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "./libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.404 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library './libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "./libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.405 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib64/System.Net.Security.Native': '(null)'.
02-04 20:15:52.405 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib64/libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': '(null)'.
02-04 20:15:52.405 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib64/libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': '(null)'.
02-04 20:15:52.405 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'System.Net.Security.Native': 'dlopen failed: library "System.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.406 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.406 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.407 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'System.Net.Security.Native': 'dlopen failed: library "System.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.407 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library './libSystem.Net.Security.Native': 'dlopen failed: library "./libSystem.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.408 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library './libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "./libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.408 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library './libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "./libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.408 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib64/libSystem.Net.Security.Native': '(null)'.
02-04 20:15:52.408 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib64/libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': '(null)'.
02-04 20:15:52.409 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib64/libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': '(null)'.
02-04 20:15:52.410 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'libSystem.Net.Security.Native': 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.411 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.413 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so': 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.413 D/Mono    (30702): DllImport error loading library 'libSystem.Net.Security.Native': 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
02-04 20:15:52.413 W/Mono    (30702): DllImport unable to load library 'dlopen failed: library "libSystem.Net.Security.Native" not found'.
**System.DllNotFoundException:** 'System.Net.Security.Native assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)'
```

I've also attached a screenshot of the packages I have installed as well as my references.

[image: Installed Packages]

[image]

I'm also getting this Warning, but I'm not sure if it's related.

`XA5302: Two processes may be building this project at once. Lock file exists at path: C:\Users\user\Documents\Downloads\XamarinScannerAndroid\XamarinScannerAndroid\XamarinScannerAndroid\obj\Debug\81\.__lock`

I'm afraid I've exhausted all of my googling abilities. If you need anything else (code snippets/screenshots/etc..) please let me know. Thanks!

**Edit 1:**
Adding a screenshot of my Android options page as well, including linking options.

[image]

Comment: What's your linker look like for the Android project?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with that. Where can I find the linker? Is this what you're referring to? 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker

Comment: Found it. Added to original post.

Comment: @Zack F  Have you solved this problem? I also ran into this and do not know what to do.

Comment: @Manul74 Yes I did. Don't remember exactly what I did unfortunately. I've added my code for that section into the OP so you can compare to yours. If I remember correctly, it was something to do with the connection string. The example they gave in some docs wasn't correct or had an extra argument I didn't need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work a while ago. Received some comments about this so I'm adding my code below for you to compare to yours/steal. From what I remember, my issue had something to do with the connection string I was using. I think the example I found had an extra parameter that was messing things up maybe?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using Xamarin.Forms;


namespace MyApp
{
    class DBConnection
    {
        private string connectionString;
        private SqlConnection connection;

        public DBConnection(string connString) 
        {
            connectionString = connString;
        }


        internal void Initialize()
        {
            CreateSQLConnection();
        }

        private void CreateSQLConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                connection = null;
                connection = new SqlConnection();
                connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
           
                if (connection != null)
                {
                    //open connection
                    connection.Open();

                    Console.WriteLine("LOG: connection established");
                    Global.gsConnectionStatus = true;

                    connection.Close();
                }
               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //ErrorHandling Here
                string exMessage = ex.Source + ex.Message + ex.ToString();
                MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "MS_Error", exMessage);
            }

        }

        public DataSet ExecuteSP(string procedureName, Dictionary<string, string> paramList)
        {
            // 1.  create a command object identifying the stored procedure
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(procedureName, connection);

            // 2. set the command object so it knows to execute a stored procedure
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // 3. add parameters to command, which will be passed to the stored procedure
            foreach (var param in paramList)
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue(param.Key, param.Value);
            }

            DataSet DSet = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                // execute the command
                //var Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                }

                SqlDataAdapter dbTable = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                dbTable.Fill(DSet);
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                //ErrorHandling Here
                string exMessage = ex.Source + ex.Message + ex.ToString();
                MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "MS_Error", exMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //ErrorHandling Here
                string exMessage = ex.Source + ex.Message + ex.ToString();
                MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "MS_Error", exMessage);
            }


            connection.Close();
            return DSet;

            
            
            
        }

    }
}
```

And here's my Connection string

```
gsConnectionString = "Data Source = tcp:111.111.111.111; Initial Catalog = AndroidDev_db; User ID = user; Password = pass";
```

Answer (score 0):

The new Microsoft SqlClient driver for SQL Server is **Microsoft.Data.SqlClient**.
Can you give the [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/) a try instead of **System.Data.SqlClient**?

FYI: This new provider supports .NET core.